# Java Memory Model: is the assignment guaranteed to be visible from the other thread?

Tags: java, memory, thread-safety

Consider this program:

```
public class Test {
    private int i = 1;

    public void f() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i != 2)
                    throw new AssertionError("i != 2");
            }
        };
        i = 2;
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
}
```

According to the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4), in `run()`, `i` is guaranteed to be equal to 2, at least because:

> A call to `start()` on a thread [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) any actions in the started thread.

So `i = 2` *happens-before* `if (i != 2)`. So far, so good.

But what if we don't start any thread after the assignment:

```
public class Test {
    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private int i = 1;

    public void f() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i != 2)
                    throw new AssertionError("i != 2");
            }
        };
        i = 2;
        EXECUTOR.execute(runnable);
    }
}
```

The previous rule does not apply. **What guarantees that `i = 2` *happens-before* the execution of `run()` in that case?**

Does assigning the variable before creating the `Runnable` have any affect on the *happens-before order*:

```
public class Test {
    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private int i = 1;

    public void f() {
        i = 2;
        EXECUTOR.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i != 2)
                    throw new AssertionError("i != 2");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

?

Comment: *"Does assigning the variable before creating the Runnable have any affect on the happens-before order?"* No, it doesn't. Not without any of the cases listed by the documentation you've linked to.

Comment: Ultimately `run()` will not be invoked until `start()` is invoked on the `Thread` object by the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, resulting in the same behavior between your first two examples. [Source code reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java?av=f#950)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `ExecutorService` Javadoc:

> Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task.

Comment: Ah, that's a good reason. Thank you. However, using `ExecutorService` was a simplification, my real problem is about [`runOnUiThread()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) on Android. Is it the same reason?